# Error Generating XML Document from object

Tags: xml-serialization

I am wishing to serialize a complex object for returning from a web service request. Here are my assumptions. I need to have the serialized (deflated) object in an XML document (as opposed to a string) before returning to the calling client. I "believe" I am deserializing just fine it is just a matter of getting it loaded into the XMLDocument. However I could be wrong and the deserialization may be wrong therefore the XmlDocument blows up. Here is the code:

My Complex Object:

```
namespace ABCTest
{
    [XmlRoot("TapRoot")]
    public class UserDetails
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public String AccountName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My serialization code:

```
FYi: UsrDtls == List<UserDetails>

XmlSerializer Obj2XML = new XmlSerializer(UsrDtls.GetType());
Stream strWriter = Stream.Null;
XmlWriter XWriter = new XmlTextWriter(strWriter, Encoding.Unicode);
XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();

Obj2XML.Serialize(XWriter, lst_Exercises);
string abc = Obj2XML.ToString(); //debugging line to attempt to browse the obj2xml object
XDoc.LoadXml(abc);

return XDoc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea where you learned about web services in .NET. Just return the object. The web service infrastructure will take care of it.

You don't say whether you're using WCF services or the legacy ASMX services. The ASMX services should not be used for new development.

If you still have trouble when you "just return it", then please post the details of any exceptions you receive.

Comment: Indeed the WCF framework will serialize it for the return. I was mostly doing an academic experiment launching a WCF workflow from a TestMethod and I didn't want to go through all the hassle of creating a client as it was my understanding that the WCF Test Client with VS2012 can not handle workflow services. While I did know technically your point about the .NET framework / WCF doing the work your theme is valid. There is much I do not know and I am very grateful to experts like yourself who are willing to share their time and knowledge.